# redefine path with trailing backslash

Tags: url

The following MWE works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\path}[1]{hidden for privacy}
\begin{document}
\path{C:\User\John Doe}
\end{document}
```

With a trailing backslash (`\path{C:\User\John Doe\}`) it won't compile. I've got

```
Runaway argument?
{C:\User \John Doe\} \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \path.
```

How can I redefine `\path` that it works with trailing backslashes, too?

Comment: TeX interprets `\}` as a control sequence, so it does not recognize it as closing bracket for the argument of \path.  If you use a space after the trailing backslash it should work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to change the style of `\path`, use: `\DeclareUrlCommand`

Comment: You should probably use the `\}` in the example as well, such that people who naïvely tests the example sees that the example works just fine.

Comment: an existing document should be prepared for publishing. As there are private data in it (e.g. in `\path{}`) the existing document should not be touched but with some redefinitions the private data should be replaced

Comment: @DG' The OP is trying to make a `\path` like macro, that just ignores the argument, but the bracing rules should be the same as the original `\path`

Comment: @DG'  Come to think about it `xparse` and the `v` specifier can do this, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xparse` and its `v` type argument specifier. If your LaTeX installation is 100% up to date, `xparse` is already build into latex

```
\RenewDocumentCommand\path{v}{hidden for privacy}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
%\renewcommand{\path}[1]{hidden for privacy}
\RenewDocumentCommand\path{v}{hidden for privacy}
\begin{document}
\path{C:\User\John Doe\}
\end{document}
```

Similar with `xparse` explicitly loaded

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{url}
%\renewcommand{\path}[1]{hidden for privacy}
\RenewDocumentCommand\path{v}{»Path hidden for privacy«}
\begin{document}
\path{C:\User\John Doe\}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This also supports the syntax `\path|...|`