# How to redefine path for replacing its content (e.g. sensitive data) with a placeholder in different contexts?

Tags: errors, url

The solution using `xparse` with the following redefinition (see [redefine path with trailing backslash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569678/redefine-path-with-trailing-backslash))

```
\RenewDocumentCommand\path{v}{hidden for privacy}
```

does not seem to work in all contexts.

For example, the following MWE using path without a trailing backslash within a `footnote` does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{url}
\RenewDocumentCommand\path{v}{Path hidden for privacy}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\path{C:\User\John Doe}}
\end{document}
```

Here, I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: The verbatim command '\path' cannot be used inside an
(LaTeX3)        argument.
```

And when using a path argument with a trailing backslash within a `footnote`, it doesn't work due to another error (runaway argument?):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{url}
\RenewDocumentCommand\path{v}{Path hidden for privacy}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\path{C:\User\John Doe\}}
\end{document}
```

The error message for this MWE is as follows:

```
Runaway argument?
{\path {C:\User \John Doe\}} \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \@footnotetext.
```

Is there a way to redefine `path` to replace its content with a placeholder that also works within other contexts like `footnote`?

Comment: That is to be expected one cannot use verbatim-like macros in arguments to other macros, same as with \verb+test+

Comment: Is there a way to redefine path so that it works in the same contexts as the original version and with the same argument, but replaces its content by a placeholder?

Comment: No idea, I would never promote the use of ``\`` in path names in the first place.

Comment: You do not need to use `C:\User\John Doe` tex will accept `C:/User/John Doe` then you do not need any verbatim handling

Comment: I need to have backslashes in my path argument when I'm dealing with Windows paths.